# CurrentCell is changed to a row that isn't SelectedItem in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that is part of a DataTemplate that is assigned to the ContentTemplate of a TabControl.  The TabControl's ItemsSource is bound to a collection and, as such, the DataContext for the DataGrid changes to a new collection once each Tab is selected.  Currently, there are bindings for ItemsSource and SelectedItem on the DataGrid.

When I move through the tabs the DataGrid is able to keep the selected row synchronized properly but the problem I'm having is that CurrentCell is always set to the first column and first row regardless of what SelectedItem equals.

I've tried setting the CurrentCell property when the DataContext changes for the DataGrid but the DataGrid always resets it back to the first row and first column.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish keeping the CurrentCell on the same Row as SelectedItem when DataContext changes?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (where dg is the DataGrid):

```
   DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.SelectedItem, dg.Columns[0]);
   dg.CurrentCell = cellInfo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When are you able to successfully do this?  I've tried to do it when DataContextChanged is fired as well as CurrentCellChanged (in which case I look for a mismatch of the current cell's Item property and the grid's SelectedItem).  Neither of which seem to work.